# Order of Contact between Folium of Descartes and Circle

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Just for context, I will provide the definition for contact between two curves:

> If the Taylor expansions of function $f(x)$ and function $g(x)$ centered around point $x = a$ are the same up to terms of the n-th order, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have a contact of n-th order.

---

I am trying to find the order of contact at the points of intersection between the following two curves:

i) $x^3 + y^3 = xy$ (Folium of Descartes where $a = \frac{1}{3}$)

ii) $x^2 + y^2 = x$ (Circle of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ with center at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$)

Since the process of finding the points of intersection are rather trivial, I won't show working for this. The points of intersection between the two curves are $(0, 0)$ and $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

The order of contact at point $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ isn't very interseting, as it's pretty clear from the graph that the two curves only intersect each other and don't share a tangent. Thus, the two curves have a contact of zero order at $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$.

The problem becomes much more interseting at the point $(0,0)$. I first noticed that the Folium of Descartes has two tangents at $(0, 0)$: a vertical tangent and a horizontal tangent. If we parameterize the Folium of Descartes in the following way:
$$(\frac{t}{1+t^3}, \frac{t^2}{1+t^3})$$
then we obtain the "lower branch" of the Folium and get the horizontal tangent at $t=0$. Since the circle has a vertical tangent at $(0, 0)$, the circle and the "lower branch" of the Folium have a contact of order zero.

Alternatively, if we parameterize the Folium in the following way:
$$(\frac{t^2}{1+t^3}, \frac{t}{1+t^3})$$
then we obtain the "upper branch" of the Folium and the vertical tangent at $t = 0$. Now, let us investigate the derivatives of the Folium and circle:

> *Derivatives of the Folium*
>
> $$\text{First Derivative = } \frac{\frac{1-2t^3}{(1+t^3)^2}}{\frac{-t(t^3-2)}{(1+t^3)^2}} = \frac{2t^3-1}{t(t^3-2)}$$
> $$\text{Second Derivative = } \frac{[6t^3(t^3-2)^2+2(t^6-7t^3+1)(1-2t^3)](1+t^3)}{t^3(t^3-2)^3}$$

> *Derivatives of the Circle*
>
> To keep the sense of description consistent with the Folium, we will parameterize the circle like the following:
> $$(\frac{1}{2}\cos(-t) + \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\sin(-t))$$
>
> $$\text{First Derivative = } \cot(t)$$
>
> $$\text{Second Derivative = } \frac{2}{\sin^3(t)}$$

It's pretty clear that all of these derivatives are undefined at the point $(0, 0)$, and I am fairly certain all higher derivatives will be undefind as well.

Since all of the derivatives are undefined, I was tempted to just conclude that it's not possible to ascertain an order for the contact between the "upper branch" of the Folium and the circle.

An alternative conclusion would be that the two curves have a contact of infinite order, but this seems wrong to me. If we consider the vertical line $x = 0$ and the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 0$, they share a tangent at $(0, 0)$ but the curvature of the two curves are wildly different. Thus, I would be hesistant to say $x= 0$ and $x^2 + y^2 = x$ have a contact of infinite order at $(0, 0)$ just because their derivatives are undefined at $(0, 0)$.

---

However, from looking at the graphs, I was fairly certain that they "upper branch" of the Folium and circle should have at least a contact of order 2.

Thus, I decided to investigate the curvature of the two curves:

> $$\text{Curvature of the Folium = } \frac{[-6t^3(t^3-2)^2-2(t^6-7t^3+1)(1-2t^3)](1+t^3)}{[t^2(t^3-2)^2 + (1-2t^3)^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
> $$\text{Curvature of the Circle = } -2$$

The curvature of the folium at $t = 0$ is also $-2$. I differentiated the curvature formula for the folium using WolramAlpha and found that the value of derivative of the curvature formula at $t=0$ is $0$, which is the same as the derivative of the curvature for the circle.

From all of the analysis I have done till now, I would like to conclude that the "upper branch" of the Folium and the circle has a contact of order three, but this goes against the definition of order of contact I was given.

Am I over-complicating this? Is my definition of order of contact inaccurate? I'm feeling pretty lost on this, I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have vertical tangents at the origin, you want to think about both curves as graphs of functions of $y$ near $y=0$. Let's represent the (upper branch of the) folium of Descartes by $x=f(y)$ and the circle by $x=g(y)$. You can't work with arbitrary parametrizations and expect to get anything meaningful.

You parametrized the folium by $x=\dfrac{t^2}{1+t^3}$, $y=\dfrac t{1+t^3}$, and so
$$\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dx/dt}{dy/dt} = \frac{t(t^3-2)}{2t^3-1}.$$
Using this and the chain rule, we get
$$\frac{d^2x}{dy^2} = \frac d{dy}\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac d{dt}\left(\frac{t(t^3-2)}{2t^3-1}\right)\Big/\dfrac{dy}{dt} = \frac{2(t^3+1)^4}{(1-2t^3)^3}.$$
Thus, $f'(0)=0$ (which was obvious) and $f''(0)=2$.

For the circle, I'll leave it to you to work out. Again, $g'(0)=0$ and $g''(0)=2$ (if you know about curvature, the curvature of a circle of radius $1/2$ is indeed $2$). Here you can solve explicitly for $g(y) = \frac12\left(1-\sqrt{1-4y^2}\right)$ or you can use implicit differentiation, again being careful with the chain rule.

Now, what about third and fourth derivatives? I'll let you do the computation, but chain rule once again will tell us that $f'''(0)=0$ and $f^{(\text{iv})}(0)=0$.
Since $g$ is obviously an even function, we'll deduce that $g'''(0)=0$, as well; it turns out that $g^{(\text{iv})}(0)=24$.

So, indeed, the two curves have contact order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

We can obtain the Taylor development of $y$ as a function of $x$ by indeterminate coefficients. If we set

$$y:=ax^2+bx^3+cx^4+dx^5$$ and plug in $x^3+y^3=xy$ by identifying the low order terms and we obtain
$a=d=1,b=c=0$. So $$y=x^2+x^5+o(x^5).$$

Note that the computation can be made very easy by adding terms one at a time.

The development of the circle is more classical and we have

$$y=x^2+x^4+o(x^4),$$ which matches to the third degree.

Comment: Except you really want $x=x(y)$ in both cases ... But Taylor expansion is an excellent approach. I opted to emphasize the chain rule viewpoint for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, I noticed (too late) that I swapped the axis. But that does not change the conclusion.

Comment: Except this is not correct …